# Why it still says that "FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value"

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

I'd like to create some layers when doing tensorboard. I defined all the variables and put the name into each of them. Of course I used `init = tf.global_variables_initializer()` and `sess.run('init')` to make sure that every variables being defined. But the weird thing is, the error

```
Attempting to use uninitialized value Layers/output_layer/weight_out/W_out" still happened in W_out, so as W1_Hidden_1 and W2_Hidden_2...
```

Does anyone can help me with it? Here is my code anyway

```
with tf.name_scope('Layers'):
# Initializers
weight_initializer = tf.contrib.layers.variance_scaling_initializer(factor=1.0, mode="FAN_AVG", uniform=True)
bias_initializer = tf.zeros_initializer()

with tf.name_scope('Hidden_layer_1'):
    with tf.name_scope('weight_1'):
        W_hidden_1 = tf.Variable(weight_initializer([n_stocks, n_neurons_1]), name = 'W_Hidden_1')
    with tf.name_scope('bias_1'):
        bias_hidden_1 = tf.Variable(bias_initializer([n_neurons_1]), name = 'Bias_Hidden_1')
    with tf.name_scope('hidden_1_output'):
        hidden_1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(X, W_hidden_1), bias_hidden_1))

with tf.name_scope('Hidden_layer_2'):
    with tf.name_scope('weight_2'):
        W_hidden_2 = tf.Variable(weight_initializer([n_neurons_1, n_neurons_2]), name = 'W_Hidden_2')
    with tf.name_scope('bias_2'):
        bias_hidden_2 = tf.Variable(bias_initializer([n_neurons_2]), name = 'Bias_Hidden_2')
    with tf.name_scope('hidden_2_output'):
        hidden_2 = tf.nn.relu(tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_1, W_hidden_2), bias_hidden_2))

with tf.name_scope('output_layer'):
    with tf.name_scope('weight_out'):
        W_out = tf.Variable(weight_initializer([n_neurons_2, 1]), name = 'W_out')
    with tf.name_scope('bias_out'):
        bias_out = tf.Variable(bias_initializer([1]), name = 'Bias_out')
    with tf.name_scope('output'):
        output = tf.transpose(tf.add(tf.matmul(hidden_2, W_out), bias_out))

with tf.name_scope('loss'):
    # Cost function
    loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(output - Y))
    tf.summary.scalar('loss', loss)

with tf.name_scope('train'):
    # Optimizer
    train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)

# Init
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(init)
    writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('logs/', sess.graph)
```